# Golang правильно ли я использую интерфейсы

Tags: golang, интерфейс

Помогите пожалуйста понять, правильно ли я использую интерфейс в ниже приведенном коде

```
package controllers
import (
    "../models"
)
func GetShedule()  {
    s := models.Shedule{}
    models.Get(&s)
}
```

_

```
package models

import "fmt"

type Shedule struct {
    Specname, Fio, Cab, VP1, VP2, Dayw string
}

type IGetShedule interface {
    Get()
}

func (s *Shedule) Get() {
    s.Specname = "specname"
    s.Fio = "fio"
    s.Cab = "cab"
    s.VP1 = "vp1"
    s.VP2 = "vp2"
    s.Dayw = "dayw"
}

func Get(s IGetShedule)  {
    s.Get()
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Обработку ошибок сознательно не использую чтобы не усложнять этот код.
Или как бы вы написали его.
(это часть REST сервиса, из controllers вызывается модель)

еще один из вариантов

```
package controllers

import (
    "../models"
    "fmt"
)

func Shedule()  {
    s := models.Shedule{}
    models.SheduleFunc(&s, "get")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

__

```
package models

type Shedule struct {
    Specname, Fio, Cab, VP1, VP2, Dayw string
}

type IGetShedule interface {
    Get()
    Put()
}

func (s *Shedule) Get() {
    s.Specname = "specnget"
    s.Fio = "get"
    s.Cab = "get"
    s.VP1 = "get"
    s.VP2 = "get"
    s.Dayw = "dget"
}

func (s *Shedule) Put()  {
    s.Specname = "put"
    s.Fio = "put"
    s.Cab = "put"
    s.VP1 = "put"
    s.VP2 = "put"
    s.Dayw = "dput"
}

func SheduleFunc(s IGetShedule, param string)  {
    switch param {
    case "get": s.Get()
    case "put": s.Put()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы просто хотите попрактиковаться в создании интерфейсов и думаете куда его всунуть?). На сколько знаю, принято создавать интерфейс в том пакете, который его использует. Т.е. ваш пакет `models` описывает типы данных и их методы, он предлагает взаимодействовать с эти типами через описанные методы, поэтому ему интерфейсы не нужны (уже есть методы). А пакет `controllers` хочет пользоваться этими типами и сам решает как это делать - через существующие методы, или создать интерфейс для удобства. В вашем примере, действительно, создание интерфейса избыточно, так как можно свободно вызывать методы типа `Shedule`. Но если появляется новый тип, скажем, `Shedule2`, то уже можно создать интерфейс, чтобы единообразно взаимодействовать с обоими типами данных.

```
package models

type Shedule struct {
    Specname, Fio, Cab, VP1, VP2, Dayw string
}

func (s *Shedule) Get() string {
    // do smth.
    return fmt.Srintf("%+v", s)
}

func (s *Shedule) Put()  {
    // do smth.
}

type Shedule2 struct {
    Specname, Fio, Cab, VP1, VP2, Dayw string
}

func (s *Shedule2) Get() string {
    // do smth.
    return fmt.Srintf("%+v", s)
}

func (s *Shedule2) Put()  {
    // do smth.
}
```

-

```
package controllers

type IGetShedule interface {
    Get() string
    Put()
}

func Shedule(s IGetShedule) {
    result = s.Get
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

-

```
package main

import "controllers"
import "models"

func main() {
    s := models.Shedule{}
    controllers.Shedule(s) // Print result
    s2 := models.Shedule2{}
    controllers.Shedule(s2) // Print result
}
```

Т.е в функцию `Shedule(s IGetShedule)` мы теперь можем передавать как тип `Shedule`, так и тип `Shedule2`. Нет надобности писать две одинаковые функции для каждого типа.

Comment: Да именно попрактиковаться... спасибо за пример, я пока разбирался сам пришел к такому же примеру.

Answer (score 0):

Интерфейсы нужны только если имеются несколько конкретных типов с которыми надо работать единообразно, обобщая их поведение (методы).
Если в models.Get планируется передавать только экземпляры models.Shedule (а судя по названию интерфейса это так), то интерфейс с одним единственным типом его реализующим, будет являться абсолютно лишней абстракцией.
Скорее всего, функции models.Get вместо интерфейса следует принимать *Shedule.

Comment: Добавил второй пример, это тоже избыточно?
И не могли бы вы показать на моем примере работу интерфейса с несколькими типами

Comment: Второй пример как раз подходит. Метод, который принимает интерфейс не заботится об истинном типе структуры.